# Extracting date from within a Varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the data as below in one of the column.
`SEMANA 50-15 (13-12-15)`
Datatype : `Varchar`

I want to convert above data to this format `2015-12-13` in Microsoft- SQL.
Please help me with the syntax.

Comment: Can the brackets only ever appear once or could you have data that looks like SEMANA(b) 50-15 (13-12-15)? Is the date always 8 digits (or could you have (1-1-15 for example)?

Comment: you've got a number or answers, many of which have been upvoted - do any of them provide a solution for you?

Answer (score 1):

If the date is always in parenthesis and there is only one pair of parenthesis and the format is `dd-mm-yy` (Italian) the following could help.

It uses `charindex()` to locate the positions of the parenthesis and extracts the substring between them using `substring()`. That substring is then converted to a `date` and converted back to a `varchar` with the desired format.

```
SELECT convert(varchar,
               convert(date,
                       substring(<column>,
                                 charindex('(',
                                           <column>)
                                 +
                                 1,
                                 charindex(')',
                                           <column>)
                                 -
                                 charindex('(',
                                           <column>)
                                 -
                                 1),
                       5),
               20)
       FROM <table>;
```

Replace `<table>` and `<column>` with your column and table name.

Answer (score 1):

Removing all test until the first bracket and replacing second bracket, casting the date with the conversion format dd/mm/yy and casting back to char(10) - this does require all rows to have valid dates in the brackets.

```
SELECT
  convert(char(10),
    convert(date,REPLACE(STUFF(col,1,charindex('(',col),''), ')', ''), 3), 126)
FROM (values('SEMANA 50-15 (13-12-15)'), ('TEST (18-1-18)')) x(col)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the date is always at the end and is always in 'DD-MM-YY)' format (i.e. there are 8 characters in the date and the date ends one character before the end) then this should do it:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, REPLACE(SUBSTRING(YourFieldName, LEN(YourFieldName)-8,8),'-','/'), 3) 
FROM YourTableName
```

To break it down this is assuming that is can find the start of the date eight characters in from the end (so must be in DD-MM-YY format), it extracts the date with the `SUBSTRING` command. It then does a `REPLACE` to change '-' to '/' in order that the `CONVERT` command will work and return a date in the format you have specified.

Note that the above returns a `Date`, if you specifically need to return a `VARCHAR` then you can apply a second `CONVERT`, see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp or the [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more information on the different options for `CONVERT` if you are interested.

Comment: Why to use second hand documentation from w3schools if you can have [first hand documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) from Microsoft?

Comment: I'll add that link too! :)

Comment: This returns a date, not a varchar. More importantly - this will not work with 1 digit dates and months unless they are padded with a 0

Comment: That's correct - it's making the supposition that the format is DD-MM-YY (as stated). I asked the original poster some questions on that but he hasn't replied yet and there isn't the detail in the question to know the full dataset. If it's not the case then as you say this won't work. And yes it's returning a date - I'll add a note to that effect, cheers.

Comment: @d219 . .  . `RIGHT()` makes more sense than using `SUBSTR()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could to the following for a simple `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE <TABLE > 
SET    <COLUMN > = LEFT(<COLUMN >, PATINDEX('%(%', <COLUMN >)) -- left part of string 
       + CAST(CONVERT(
           DATE,
           SUBSTRING(
               <COLUMN >,
               PATINDEX('%(%', <COLUMN >) + 1,
               PATINDEX('%)%', <COLUMN >) - 1 - PATINDEX('%(%', <COLUMN >)
           ),
           5
       ) AS VARCHAR(12))-- converted part of string 
 + RIGHT(<COLUMN >, LEN(<COLUMN >) - PATINDEX('%)%', <COLUMN >) + 1) -- right part of string
```

<sup>Please replace `<COLUMN>` with your column name, and `<TABLE>` with the name of your table in the above script</sup>

I derived the statement from the following testing environment:

```
DECLARE @vValue1 VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @iStartVal INT
DECLARE @iEndVal INT
DECLARE @iStringLength INT
DECLARE @iSearchStringLenght INT

SET @vValue1 = 'SEMANA 50-15 (13-12-15)'

SET @iStartVal = PATINDEX('%(%', @vValue1)
SET @iEndVal = PATINDEX('%)%', @vValue1)
SET @iStringLength = @iEndVal -1 - @iStartVal

PRINT @vValue1
PRINT @iStartVal
PRINT @iEndVal 
PRINT @iStringLength

PRINT CONVERT(
                 DATE,
                 SUBSTRING(
                     @vValue1,
                     PATINDEX('%(%', @vValue1) + 1,
                     PATINDEX('%)%', @vValue1) - 1 - PATINDEX('%(%', @vValue1)
                 ),
                 5
             ) 
PRINT LEFT(@vValue1, @iStartVal)
PRINT RIGHT(@vValue1, LEN(@vValue1) - @iEndVal + 1)

PRINT LEFT(@vValue1, PATINDEX('%(%', @vValue1)) -- left part of string 
           + CAST(CONVERT(
               DATE,
               SUBSTRING(
                   @vValue1,
                   PATINDEX('%(%', @vValue1) + 1,
                   PATINDEX('%)%', @vValue1) - 1 - PATINDEX('%(%', @vValue1)
               ),
               5
           ) AS VARCHAR(12)) -- converted part of string 
     + RIGHT(@vValue1, LEN(@vValue1) - PATINDEX('%)%', @vValue1) + 1)
```

Comment: You're adding `varchar`s and `date`s. That throws an error.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed.